# Using method on previous method's return value, C#

Tags: c#, .net

For example, I understand that I am able to do this:

```
string x = Int32.Parse("123").ToString();
```

Instead of:

```
int y = Int32.Parse("123");
string x = y.ToString();
```

because `Parse()` method returns and integer and then I can use `ToString()` method on an integer. But what is this technique called? I couldn't put it into words to google for more information. Is it yummies of .NET/high-level programming, or are you able to do this in low-level programming languages too, like C?

Comment: I would call it call or method chaining.

Comment: This should possible in almost any language that allows for objects with methods that can return other objects.  It can even be pulled off in C by storing function pointers inside of structs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is called **Method chaining**. Here is the details:

[Universal method chaining](http://interactiveasp.net/blogs/spgilmore/archive/2009/04/07/universal-method-chaining-in-c-3-5.aspx)

You may want to see this article with respect to LINQ

[Understanding LINQ to Objects (2) Method Chaining](http://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/archive/2010/03/08/understanding-linq-to-objects-2-method-chaining.aspx)

*Example from the Article:*

```
int[] source = new int[] { 0, 1, -2, 3, 24, 6, 3 };
var results = source.Where(item => item > 0 && item < 10)
                    .OrderBy(item => item)
                    .Select(item => item.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
```

Answer (score 4):

It's known as method chaining. See here for a little more information: [Method chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining)

I think an important point to be taken from the above wiki is;

Method chaining is not required. It only potentially improves readability and reduces the amount of source code. It is the core concept behind building a [Fluent Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface).

Comment: yep, I've always referred to it as such

Answer (score 1):

It's called "Method chaining" get that into Google and you should get some helpful results!

Comment: You link points to `how to install screensaver programmatically?`

Comment: I've edited out the link - feel free to add in something else, but that had *no relation whatsoever* to method-chaining.

Comment: Ah sorry! Had a different link still on my clipboard from a previous question then. Thanks for the fix!

Answer (score 1):

It's method chaining, which taken to more of an extreme can be used to create fluent interfaces. This is the basis of (method chain stated) LINQ.

As this gives a larger surface area in which exceptions can occur, it's not recommended if you need to check your assumptions along the way (checking for nulls, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Yep.. As every one said, this is a method chaining. and this exists even in jQuery if you have  noticed.

$('#id').show(300).html('XYZ').hide(500);